# Drag and Drop file size is wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, electron

I am implementing drag & drop functionality in electron + react application.

here is my drop event listener

```
handleDrop = event => {
 event.preventDefault();
 if (event.dataTransfer.files && event.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {
    this.props.handleDrop(event.dataTransfer.files)
  }};
```

and parent component i use this method

```
  handleDrop = (files) => {
   let fileList = this.state.files
   for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (!files[i].name) return
    fileList.push({
      name : files[i].name,
      size : files[i].size,
      path : files[i].path,
      lastModifiedDate : files[i].lastModifiedDate
   })
 }
 this.setState({files: fileList})}
```

But i am getting wrong file size or 0 for some files. How can i get original file size in drag and drop onDrop event??

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking correct. May be, the reason of file size wrong detecting is you drag file from zip-archive. One day i have been spent more than 4 hour to understand this :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33426746)